# when i give input().split() in code and if i give input with space like 2 3 it throws error

Tags: python

If I give `input().split()` it throws error but after trying this `[input().split()]` it doesn't throw error what happens in background

```
inputs = [input().split()]

total = 0
for a,b in inputs:
    print(eval(a) % eval(b))
```

Comment: What does input contains? What are you trying to do?

Comment: When you use `or a,b in inputs:´ the expectation is that `inputs` is a list containing lists with 2 elements. In your case something like `[ [ 7, 3 ] ]`. Put in a few print() statements to understand the difference.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general, it's helpful to include what your input was and what the error is. Also, if you can, include what output you expect

Comment: Be *very* careful using `eval`; ensure you have [complete control over its input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/ddg#1832957).

Answer (score 0):

`split()` function takes arguments and splits the string according to the character you entered**(default space character)** and the return list.

So, when you don't use [], `split()` function returns [a value, b value] but if you use [], `split()` function returns [[a value, b value]]. When you're trying to access two values like a and b, you should have 2 values in the indexes.

1. In first use-case scenario, you don't have two values because a and b values are seperate indexes like [0] and [1].
2. But in second use-case scenario, a and b values are same index like [0][0] and [0][1]. I mean, they're both elements of index 0. When you loop through index 0, you can get the values ​​in order

I think you can understand better with code;

```
inputs = input().split()
total = 0
for a in inputs:
    print(a)
```

In this scenario, for example you enter "3 5". This string splits according to the space character and you will get ["3","5"]. In foor loop, you can access the values in order, so for loop works 2 times and assign 2 times.

```
inputs = [input().split()]
total = 0
for a,b in inputs:
    print(a,b)
```

But in this scenario, for example you enter "3 5" again. This string splits according to the space character and you will get [["3","5"]]. In for loop, you can access both at the same time because those values are at the same index. When you access array[0], you can take both a and b values.

Answer (score 0):

Say, your input was

```
2 3
```

When you do `input().split()`, you get a list of strings, in this example `["2", "3"]`, but later in the code you're trying to go through the list as if it contained pairs `a, b`. That causes an error, because neither `"2"`, nor `"3"` is a pair. The `for` loop is trying to assign

```py
a, b = "2"
```

and fails.

But when you do `[input().split()]`, you get a list of lists, like `[["2", "3"]]`. So the `for` loop runs only once, with

```py
a, b = ["2", "3"]
```

and the code works.